# Can you use both copy mechanism and BPE?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, rnn

I read to alleviate the problem of Out of Vocabulary (OOV), there are two techniques:

1. BPE
2. Copy mechanism

It appears to me they are two orthogonal approaches.

Can we combine the two, i.e.,  we use both the copy mechanism and BPE? Are there any work out there that combines the two? I cant find any.